# Wordpress Shortcode Returning Number 1? How To Remove?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I was wondering whether anyone would know why the following code is returning a number 1 at the end? Does anyone know how to stop this from happening?

```
function get_product_images_slider() {
$product_image_output = include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/product-images-shortcode.php');
return $product_image_output;
}
add_shortcode( 'product-images', 'get_product_images_slider' );
```

my code inside the include is:

```
                         <ul class="slick  js-fader">
                            <li>
                                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="figure" width="425" height="328" itemprop="image" />
                            </li>
                            <?php
                                global $product;
                                $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

                                foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
                                { ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <?php
                                            echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'product-image', '', array( "class" => "figure", 'width' => '425', 'height' => '328', 'itemprop' => 'image' ) );
                                        ?>
                                    </li>
                            <?php }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [include function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) always returns the number one if the include is successful, and you are assigning this to a variable. You are returning this variable at the end. What are you expecting to be output?

EDIT: Here's the code you need to use:

product-images-shortcode.php

```
<?php function productShortcode() { ?>
     <ul class="slick js-fader">
         <li>
             <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
             <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="figure" width="425" height="328" itemprop="image" />
        </li>
        <?php
        global $product;
        $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
        foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
        { ?>
            <li>
                <?php
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'product-image', '', array( "class" => "figure", 'width' => '425', 'height' => '328', 'itemprop' => 'image' ) );
                ?>
            </li>
        <?php
        } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

functions.php

```
function get_product_images_slider() {
    include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/product-images-shortcode.php');
    return productShortcode();
}
add_shortcode( 'product-images', 'get_product_images_slider' );
```

So, we are using the code from the include, rather than returning the value of the incude directly.

Comment: Hi,
The include is just a file which pulls through the gallery images from the product pages, since the website is woocommerce.

Comment: Is there anyway to edit the coding so that that it doesn't return the number one? Ive use php included before within the HTML and I don't seem to get a number 1.

Comment: You are using include wrong - can you add the code in the file you are including (or the relevant bit) and I can write up an example for you

Comment: Hi James, I've just updated my post above to show the code inside my include file. I think I understand what you mean and just have the contents of the include within the function and not to use include all together, I just wanted to try this and do it this way so it was easier to manage. Was then going to try and create a shortcode so I could pass through the template I wanted to include.